# Rails Testing XHR with Post data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm just dipping my toes into Ruby and Rails and trying to get my head the whole BDD thing. I have a page that does an AJAX POST back to a controller that has a method called "sort" and passes along an array of id's like this

```
["song-section-5", "song-section-4", "song-section-6"]
```

I want to write a test for this so I came up with something like this:

```
test "should sort items" do
  xhr :post, :sort
end
```

But can't figure out how to pass along the array. Any help?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the Rails [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.1.0.rc4/actionpack/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb#L388)

```
def xml_http_request(request_method, action, parameters = nil, session = nil, flash = nil)
```

The third input to the method is "parameters". These are the params sent to your controller.

```
xhr :post, :sort, { :ids => ["song-section-5", "song-section-4", "song-section-6"] }
```

Comment: Sweet. Simpler than I thought. Thanks!

Comment: Note. `xhr` is deprecated in rails 5. Use `xhr: true` option instead.

Comment: ⬆️⬆️⬆️ You, The Real MVP

Answer (score 25):

For me, using RSpec 3.6 and Rails 5.1 the previous answer fails:

```
xhr :post, :index

# => NoMethodError: undefined method `xhr' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::XController::Index::AJAXRequest:0x007fd9eaa73778>
```

### Rails 5.0+

Instead try setting `xhr: true` like this:

```
post :index, xhr: true
```

### Background

Here's the relevant code in the [ActionController::TestCase](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/843345cae59b73e50af685ac1303a419a06b4c91/actionpack/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb#L457). Setting the `xhr` flag ends up adding the following headers:

```
if xhr
  @request.set_header "HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH", "XMLHttpRequest"
  @request.fetch_header("HTTP_ACCEPT") do |k|
    @request.set_header k, [Mime[:js], Mime[:html], Mime[:xml], "text/xml", "*/*"].join(", ")
  end
end
```

Comment: +1, this took me so long to find this, thanks so much! I was following examples of: ````xhr :post, :index````

Comment: I hope you know you just saved me an hour of hair pulling. I upgraded to Rails5 and couldn't figure out why this was breaking.

Answer (score 3):

#### The answer

```
test "should sort items" do
  post path_to_your_sort_action, params: { ids: ["song-section-5", "song-section-4", "song-section-6"] }, xhr: true, 
end
# using Rails +6 and minitest
```

#### Proof?

- Here are links to the source code, the [first](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/fe76a95b0d252a2d7c25e69498b720c96b243ea2/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/testing/integration.rb#L22) leads to the [second](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/89361447e1491c8a756e46e94df70d82595d1534/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/testing/integration.rb#L202), which contains the answer you are looking for.
- Explanation: The modern Rails stack prefers using integration tests rather than controller tests - so you'll be using `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest`. If you want to send a post request simply pass in `xhr: true`. Check the source code above.